# $x=1$ for geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I found an interesting identity regarding the Riemann zeta function:

$$  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\zeta(2k)-1)x^{2k}= \frac{x^2}{1-x^2} + \frac{1}{2} (1-\pi x \cot(\pi x) )$$

but to arrive at this identity, it is necessary to use:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k} = \frac{x^2}{1-x^2} $$

where $|x^2|<1$, because it is a geometric series.

On the other hand, pluging in $x=1$ gives us:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\zeta(2k)-1)=\frac{3}{4}$$

which is another identity. Why can we do that? Can we also use $x=i$?

Comment: You reached your identity via a method which imposed the restriction $|x|<1$. This does not necessarily mean the result is not valid outside that restriction. (In general $A\implies B\not\implies B\implies A$). There should be another way which does not impose that restriction (probably via integrals). Actually I'd probably invoke the Dirichlet eta function, not sure though.

Comment: I will leave here the link to where I found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W2Ghi9idxM . At $11:43$ the geometric series is first used with the ratio being $r=\frac{x^2}{n^2}$ , but then uses it again at $17:42$, so the ratio then would be $r=x^2$

Comment: So Im confused as to which values of $x$ I can actually plug in there.

Comment: Your first display is correct for $|x|<2$ (removable singularity on the right).  Your second display is true only for $|x|<1$ since the series diverges when $|x|\ge 1$.

Comment: "Why can we do that?": you can't. If the formula is also valid for $x=1$, this is "by chance" and you need to prove it independently.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the singularity, do not simplify too much and stay with
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\zeta(2k)-1)x^{2k}=\frac{1-3 x^2-\pi x  \left(1-x^2\right)  \cot (\pi  x)}{2 \left(1-x^2\right)}$$
$$f(i)=1-\frac{\pi}{2}   \coth (\pi )$$